# Zip Code distance in excel

Tags: excel, zipcode

I am looking for a way to get a function in excel to retrieve the distance form one zip to another. Lets say i have a list of 100,000 possible recruits and I want to sort by nearest. Id have the conference zip code and then 100,000 recruit zip codes. I'm looking to be able to just write a function =ZipCodeDistance(a2,d1) and then sort by that column. I have found a program for $65 that claims to do this, but I was wondering if there was a free way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the latitude and longitude for each zip code, you can use trigonometry to calculate the distance as the crow flies.

There is a free database [here](http://www.populardata.com/downloads.html) that you can download.

To do the calculation, see the info [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). And some actual Excel-specific calc examples are [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/latlong.htm).

Comment: Added more info on how to do the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

How to get the data and the algorithm are explained [here](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/programming-and-development/?p=634), but in C#. If your Excel VBA is OK, it shouldn't be too difficult to translate?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of the post office address for each zip code and geocode each address into a lat, long pair.  Do the same for the recruit's address and then use the formula for great circle distance.

Here's a link to a U.S. zip code database:

http://www.zipcodeworld.com/

And another to how to calculate distance between two points on the globe:

http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm